# Migrating JSP web app to JSF

Tags: java, jsp, jsf

I am pretty new to java dev & JSF framework and as an exercise to get me up to speed I am migrating a JSP web app to a JSF2 structure. I was wondering if someone could suggest a best practice for doing this?

Currently the JSP files are basically used to obtain information from the various libraries they sit on top of, and I was thinking that for JSF I need to essentially rip out the Java from these JSP files and place them in to a managed bean. These would then be referenced within the XHTML files.

Am I on the right lines or am I completely missing the point?

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have followed MVC in your jsp app, then it would be pretty easy.

- Take all the form beans from jsp and make them managed bean with proper annotation and scope
- take controller's logic to action method
- for navigation replace `forward()` and `redirect()`'s call to enabled it with JSF navigation handler
- change the view from jsp to XHTML well and do the binding with JSF EL style

Comment: thought be cautious, its not as easy as it sounds here !

Comment: @Prashant depends on the current arch of JSP app